Gradle 9.0 deprecation warning
We've got an Android project (app) which uses the following stanzas to declare its dependencies, which vary based on build flavor:
configurations {
    fooReleaseImplementation
    barReleaseImplementation
}

Where foo and bar are flavors (from the same dimension) and release is a build type.
Then we bring in the actual dependencies:
dependencies {
    fooReleaseImplementation "com.abc:def:$version"
    barReleaseImplementation "com.abc:def:$version:specialflavor@aar"
}

The idea is that the foo flavor, release build type and bar flavor, release build type have different dependencies.
Without the configuration block, Gradle complains that "method fooReleaseImplementation is not found" and "method barReleaseImplementation is not found".
Gradle 8.8 gives a warning about the configurations block:

The Configuration.fileCollection(Spec) method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Use Configuration.getIncoming().artifactView(Action) with a componentFilter instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#deprecate_filtered_configuration_file_and_filecollection_methods

I want to prepare our project for Gradle 9.0 but having trouble understanding the reason for the warning. We are not using Configuration.fileCollection.
Is this a bug in Gradle 8.8 and how it detects the deprecation, or am I missing something?
I've read the linked documentation and "the new way" example also has a configurations block, so it seems that this block, itself, has not been deprecated after all?

When you do
configurations {
    fooReleaseImplementation
    barReleaseImplementation
}

you create those configurations and then you eagerly access them. This appears to be the source of the later error, for Gradle is trying to stop you adding files to configurations that have already been accessed.
To create these configurations without the eager access, you can use the register method.
configurations {
    register('fooReleaseImplementation')
    register('barReleaseImplementation')
}


Unfortunately "register" doesn't solve the issue - same warning. Note that the Gradle 9.0 migration document uses the same "eager access" syntax as we're using in our gradle files, so I think it has to be a bug in Gradle.

When referencing existing configurations, which one cannot create or register ...

Be sure to mark configurations meant for resolution as canBeConsumed=false
or use the resolvable(String) configuration factory method to create them.

val googleImplementation by configurations
googleImplementation.isCanBeConsumed=false

val googleApi by configurations
googleApi.isCanBeConsumed=false


And the other error message seems to be fixed in Kotlin 2.0.20:

This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0.
The Configuration.fileCollection(Spec) method has been deprecated.
Solutions:

Use Configuration.getIncoming().artifactView(Action) with a componentFilter instead.


https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-67888/Remove-usages-of-deprecated-Configuration.fileCollection-method

With Kotlin 1.9.25 I get a whole different set of warnings, compared to 2.1.0.
